# iPad mini - same in Australia as UK?

Tags: ipad, cellular-carriers

I wonder if someone can shed some light on this.  I live in the UK but am travelling to Austalia for Christmas.  If I buy a cellular iPad mini in Australia, will that work when I bring it back to the UK?

Obviously I will need to put a UK SIM card in there, but apart from that, will there be any issues?

Many thanks in advance
Charlie

Answer (score 1):

According the [LTE page at Apple.com](http://www.apple.com/ipad/LTE/) the model in UK and Australia should be compatible:

Model number:

> iPad mit Retina Display (4. Generation) Modell A1460
>
> iPad mini Modell A1455

LTE Band Support:

> 1 (2100 MHz)
>   3 (1800 MHz)
>   5 (850 MHz)
>   13 (700c MHz)
>   25 (1900 MHz)

For both UK and Australia. You should be fine buying the iPad down under :)

Comment: Many thanks for the quick response - great news!